# Loop selected value from Django ManytoMany fileds

Tags: django-models

**How to get value from Many to Many Django model field**

I tried,

```
 Member.objects.get(id=2).requirement.requirement
```

Gets an output. I am excepting strings
Output

```
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f651bd18fd0>
```

Also, I tried

```
Member.objects.get(id=2).requirement.requirement.category
```

Models

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Name')
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Age')
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Requirement(models.Model):
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    requirement = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member.objects.get(id=2).requirement.requirement` is a collection/set of Category objects so you may treat it as `QuerySet` and thus you may use QuerySet API methods on it, like `.filter()`, get `.first()` or get `.all()` records. So, as it is expected that manytomany field will have multiple results you may at list iterate over them, like this:

```
for category in Member.objects.get(id=2).requirement.requirement.all():
    print(category.category) #or whatever you want to do with it
```